# generated Terrain wouldn't display in directX (C# )

Tags: c#, directx, terrain

Greetings

I genereated a terrain with this equation:

H(x,y) = (abs(sin(x * y)) + abs(sin(0,2 * x) + sin(0,4 * y)) + abs(cos(0,12 * x) + cos(0,47 * y))) * e^(0.005*(x+y))

Now, this gives me a mix of featuresize, and a nice slope. This works fine, when I plot it using scilab.

I tried to import this in a c# application.

The terrain is created in this code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D;
using Microsoft.DirectX;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Kamera_eins
{

    public partial class Terrain : Form

    {
        public double[,] DTM;
        string response ;

        public Terrain()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            response = "";
            DTM =  new double[2048/4,2048/4];


        }

        public void BoxTheSky()
        {


        }

        public void BoxTheLand()
        {

            mesh();

            surf();
        }
        public void begin()
        {

        }

        public void mesh()
        {
            response = "";
            int i = new int();
            int j = new int();
            i = 0;
            j = 0;

            for (i=0;i<2048/4 ;i++ ) {
                for (j=0;j<2048/4 ;j++ ) {
                    DTM[i,j] = Math.Abs (Math.Sin (j*i)) + Math.Abs(Math.Sin(0.2*i) * Math.Sin(0.4*j) ) + Math.Abs(Math.Cos(0.12* i) * Math.Cos(0.47*j));
                    DTM[i,j] = Math.Pow(Math.E, (0.012* (i + j)));


                }
            }

            response = "DTM  mesh ready"; 


        }

        public void surf()
        {

        }
    }
    }
```

This is kept in a file called terrain.cs, and i make this a winform, because i plan to add a simple textbox, where i can later make some sort of realtime log of the process.

Now, there is another file, and in that file, intend to display this terrain. this second file goes as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

using Microsoft.DirectX;
using Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D;
using Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput;


namespace Kamera_eins
{
    public class viewport : Form
    {
        public Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.Device device = null;
        public PresentParameters presentparameter = new PresentParameters();
        public bool device_exists;

        public bool show;

        public int HEIGHT;
        public int WIDTH;

        public string paintDesc;


        private float angle ;
        private CustomVertex.PositionColored[] vertices;
        public double[,] heightData;
        private int[] indices;
        private IndexBuffer ib;
        private VertexBuffer vb;
         private Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput.Device keyb;

        //public 


        public viewport()
        {
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(600, 600);
            this.Text = "Terrain viewport";

            WIDTH = 2048 / 4;
            HEIGHT = 2048 / 4;

            heightData = new double[HEIGHT,WIDTH];


            keyb = new Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput.Device(SystemGuid.Keyboard);
             keyb.SetCooperativeLevel(this, CooperativeLevelFlags.Background | CooperativeLevelFlags.NonExclusive);
             keyb.Acquire();

            presentparameter.Windowed = true;
            presentparameter.SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard;
            presentparameter.AutoDepthStencilFormat = DepthFormat.D16;
            presentparameter.EnableAutoDepthStencil = true;
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.Opaque, true);

            try {

            device = new Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.Device(0, Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.DeviceType.Hardware, this, CreateFlags.SoftwareVertexProcessing, presentparameter);
            device.DeviceLost += new EventHandler(this.InvalidateDeviceObjects);
            device.DeviceReset += new EventHandler(this.RestoreDeviceObjects);
            device.Disposing += new EventHandler(this.DeleteDeviceObjects);
            device.DeviceResizing += new CancelEventHandler(this.EnvironmentResizing);

            device_exists = true;


            } catch (Exception DirectException) {
            device_exists = false;  
            }



        }

        private void setcamera()
        {
            device.Transform.Projection = Matrix.PerspectiveFovLH((float)Math.PI / 4, this.Width / this.Height, 1f, 50f);
            device.Transform.View = Matrix.LookAtLH (new Vector3(0, 0, 100), new Vector3(0, 0, 0) , new Vector3(0,0,1) );
            device.RenderState.Lighting = false;
            device.RenderState.FillMode = FillMode.WireFrame;
            device.RenderState.CullMode = Cull.None;
        }


        public void declareVertex()
        {
            vb = new VertexBuffer(typeof(CustomVertex.PositionColored), HEIGHT*WIDTH, device, Usage.Dynamic | Usage.WriteOnly, CustomVertex.PositionColored.Format, Pool.Default);
            vertices = new CustomVertex.PositionColored[HEIGHT*WIDTH];

            for (int x=0;x< WIDTH;x++)            {

                for (int y=0; y< HEIGHT;y++)                {
                    vertices[x + y * WIDTH].Position = new Vector3(x, y, (float)heightData[x,y]);
                    int r = Convert.ToInt32(205 * heightData[x,y] / 200 );
                    if(r>254)
                        r = 254;

                    vertices[x + y * WIDTH].Color =  Color.FromArgb( r , 120 , 120).ToArgb();

                }
            }

            vb.SetData(vertices, 0, LockFlags.None);

        }

        public void declareIndex()
        {
            ib = new IndexBuffer(typeof(int), (WIDTH-1)*(HEIGHT-1)*6, device, Usage.WriteOnly, Pool.Default);
            indices = new int[(WIDTH-1)*(HEIGHT-1)*6];

            for (int x=0;x< WIDTH-1;x++)            {

                for (int y=0; y< HEIGHT-1;y++)                {
                    indices[(x+y*(WIDTH-1))*6] = (x+1)+(y+1)*WIDTH;
                    indices[(x+y*(WIDTH-1))*6+1] = (x+1)+y*WIDTH;
                    indices[(x+y*(WIDTH-1))*6+2] = x+y*WIDTH;

                    indices[(x+y*(WIDTH-1))*6+3] = (x+1)+(y+1)*WIDTH;
                    indices[(x+y*(WIDTH-1))*6+4] = x+y*WIDTH;
                    indices[(x+y*(WIDTH-1))*6+5] = x+(y+1)*WIDTH;
                }
            }
            ib.SetData(indices, 0, LockFlags.None);
        }



         protected override void Dispose (bool disposing)
         {

             base.Dispose(disposing);
             MessageBox.Show("");
         }


        protected virtual void InvalidateDeviceObjects(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected virtual void RestoreDeviceObjects(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected virtual void DeleteDeviceObjects(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected virtual void EnvironmentResizing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        public void run()
        {
            while(this.Created)
            {
                render();
                setcamera();


                // optional: loading the height using functional call:
                //  loadheight();

                Application.DoEvents();
            }
        }


        public void render()
        {
            if (device != null)
            {
                device.Clear(ClearFlags.Target, Color.Black, 1.0f, 0);
                device.BeginScene();

                //display terrain
                device.VertexFormat = CustomVertex.PositionColored.Format;
            device.SetStreamSource(0, vb, 0);
            device.Indices = ib;

            device.Transform.World = Matrix.Translation(-HEIGHT/2, -WIDTH/2, 0)*Matrix.RotationZ(angle) ;
            device.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleFan, 0, 0, WIDTH*HEIGHT, 0, indices.Length/3);






                //turn off lights now

                device.EndScene();
                device.Present();
                this.Invalidate();
                readkeyboard();

            }
        }

        void readkeyboard()
        {

             KeyboardState keys = keyb.GetCurrentKeyboardState();
            if (keys[Key.Delete])
            {
                angle+=0.03f;
            }
            if (keys[Key.Next])
            {
                angle-=0.03f;
            }
        }

        public void openport()
        {




        }



            protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {


                render();
                setcamera();

        }


    }
}
```

Now, yet a third file calls the world creation and display:

```
void MainFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            world = new World();
            world.setterrain();
}
```

the surf and box-somthing functions do not yet do anything.

All what i get now, is just a black window (the device.clear(... ) part) - i tried to adjust the camera .. no success

please help, i want to show the terrain in the window ....